# threads printing empty space

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

The problem is this :
I wanted to create a program to add pairs of numbers using individual threads.
This is the code:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue

print_lock = threading.Lock()
q = Queue()
numbers = [[235465645, 4345464565], [52546546546, 433453435234],     [1397675464, 5321453657], [980875673, 831345465], [120938234, 289137856], [93249823837, 32874982837]]

def addition(pair):
    num1 = pair[1]
    num2 = pair[2]
    total = num1 + num2

    with print_lock:
        print(num1, '+', num2, ':', total)

def threader():
    while True:
        pair = numbers.pop(0)
        calculator = q.get()
        addition(pair)
        q.task_done()

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    q.put(i)

q.join()
```

But when I run the program, all I get are two blank lines. I don't know what the problem is. I am using version 3.4, if that helps in any way.

I would strongly appreciate any help.
Thank you,
Muathasim Mohamed P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken indexing in...:

```
def addition(pair):
    num1 = pair[1]
    num2 = pair[2]
    (etc)
```

Python indexes from `0`, so with `len(pair)` being 2, `pair[2]` kills the thread with an `IndexError`.  Best:

```
def addition(pair):
    num1, num2 = pair
    (etc)
```

so you don't even have to recall the rather crucial detail about Python indexing -- you just unpack the 2-items sequence into two scalars, and, off you go!-)